# Regular expression for capturing values - Perl

Tags: perl

I am writing a parser that will capture the value from text file. Apart from two values I am able to capture all values.

Can some one help me out to get those two values as well?

Here is my code:

```
use warnings;

open( my $fh, "<", "$tZPath\\Diag.txt" ) || print "can't open file filename : $!\n";

my ( $aBT_Slave, $iD, $hready, $address );

while ( defined( my $line = <$fh> ) ) {

    if ( $line =~ /ID\:\s*(.+?\W+)/i ) {
        $iD = $1;
        print " Id -> $iD \n";
    }
    elsif ( $line =~ /HREADY\:\s*(.+?\W+)/i ) {
        $hready = $1;
        print " hready -> $hready \n";
    }
    elsif ( $line =~ /ADDR0\w\s*(.+?\W+)/i ) {
        $address = $1;
        print " address -> $address \n";
    }
    elsif ( $line =~ /PCNOC\_(.*?\d+)/i ) {
        $aBT_Slave = "PCNOC_" . $1;
        print " aBT_Slave -> $aBT_Slave \n";
    }
}
```

Log file content:

```
ABT PCNOC_9 ID: 0x0000430c
ABT PCNOC_9 ADDR0: 0x000000e0
ABT PCNOC_9 ADDR1: 0x00000000
ABT PCNOC_9 HREADY: 0xfffffffd
ABT PCNOC_9 Slaves: 5
Fatal Error: AHB_TIMEOUT
```

Can anyone please help me out to get the `ADDR0` value and `PCNOC_9` from the log?
Please let me know if have kept unclear expiation here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this, It will make fetching fully dynamic.

```
while (defined(my $line = <$fh>)) {
      if($line =~ /(PCNOC\_.*?\d+)\s*(\w+):\s*(.*)/i){
            print "$1 ==> $2 ==> $3\n";
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
if($line =~ /ADDR1:\s*(.*)/i){
.....
}
elsif($line =~ /ADDR0:\s*(.*)/i){
.....
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
/ADDR0\w\s*(.+?\W+)/i
      ^^
```

This fails to match because `:` is not a word char. Fix:

```
/ADDR0:\s*(.*)/
```